# Stopping unnecessary posts to PHP file

Tags: php, python, ajax

[image]

Above you can see Google's account registration page telling me that a username is already taken. Firstly, this is how I assume it is informing me:

1. Upon the text input losing focus an AJAX call is made to a file somewhere within Google's web server
2. The server (running Python I believe?) processes the username and performs a check against a database via a query.
3. Once the database has performed the query the result is returned to the server.
4. Then it is returned to the browser where it is made pretty and informs me of the result in a way that is useful to the user.

**My question** is to do with where the processing occurs. Wherever the processing is happening it is purely serving a purpose for this page. I as any person shouldn't be able to find this file where Google perform this check and post data to it and see a response. I want to find out what is stopping me, how are Google preventing me from making a check manually against this Python file that is making the check? Or are they at all?

Currently I am using PHP to do the exact same thing as Google are doing here. The PHP file that is being invoked via AJAX is in the same directory as the registration, it is called "check.php". If you were to post a username to that file on my web server you would see the response and this is what I need to stop (or should I just not be stopping it?). How can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: So, you would like to only allow the response to be 'got' via AJAX?

Comment: @BenCarey Essentially yes, and only from the registration page on my web server. You shouldn't be able to create a file on your web server and make an AJAX call to my check.php file to find out whether a username is taken or not. You shouldn't only be able to see the result of that check on my registration page. Edit: I just remembered that is cross origin and wouldn't work anyway so you are right with what you're saying 8-)

Comment: That is a very long winded way of asking how to detect an AJAX request on a PHP page! I will post an answer, you have many options

Comment: @BenCarey Thanks Ben, it is primarily because I didn't realise what I was trying to ask at first. When I've seen your answer I'll modify the question so it's more relevant :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to determine whether or not a request is via ajax, and if not, block the request...

You have several options for this (will have missed some out):

1. Attach a 'session_id' to the form and validate it on the 'check.php' page. If it is valid then proceed.
2. Look for the AJAX request header (example below). ***This is not necessarily reliable as headers can be manipulated***
3. Manipulate the header yourself using jQuery `ajax` and then test for it on 'check.php'

Example of option 2:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest'){
    // I'm AJAX!
}
```

You have other options as well, but this should be a good start...